# Lectures on Continuum Physics 1.1

Tags: vectors, geometry

This question relates to this [continuum mechanics online course](https://open.umich.edu/find/open-educational-resources/engineering/lectures-continuum-physics#unit-01-what-continuum-physics-about-remembering-vectors). So far it has excellent lectures and problem sets but no solutions.

> *Problem 1.*
>
> Show that the vector $ae_1 + be_2 + ce_3$ is normal to the plane whose equation is $ax + by + cz = d$.

I understand that the vector is just $<a,b,c>$ and so it's naturally normal to the given plane but really have no idea how to show it. I also have a few questions. is $e_1$ just another convention for $\hat{i}$? In the lecture he says that $e$ is a basis vector, but I've never really understood what a basis vector is. Can someone explain that a little?

Comment: Hi Eric, I've voted to migrate this question to [MathSE](https://math.stackexchange.edu) because, though it may arise in a physical context, this question and its answer are purely mathematical.

Comment: Later problem sets will have a stronger physics context, will they want to answer those on MathSE or am I going to end up fielding these questions on both sites?

Comment: It depends on the nature of the question.  If you were to ask about how to derive [Euler's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_laws_of_motion) for rigid body motion from the more general framework of continuum mechanics, it would be at home here because e.g. it involves taking various physically-motivated limits. On the other hand, if you ask about numerically solving the equations governing a continuum system, it would belong on [SciCompSE](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com); if you ask about the existence/uniqueness of such solutions, it would probably belong on MathSE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think for a moment about what it means for a vector $\vec v$ to be perpendicular to a plane.  What we're really saying is that for any vector $\vec w$ which *lies* in the plane, $\vec v \cdot \vec w = 0$.

Now, what does it mean for a vector to lie in the plane?  For a nice affine space like $\mathbb R^3$, it means that we can write $\vec w$ as the difference of two points $p=(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ and $q=(x_2,y_2,z_2)$ which satisfy the equation $ax+by+cz = d$ which defines the plane.

Putting that together, let $\vec v = \langle a,b,c\rangle$ and $\vec w = q-p = \langle x_2-x_1,y_2-y_1,z_2-z_1\rangle$.  Then
$$\vec v \cdot \vec w = a(x_2-x_1) + b(y_2-y_1) +c(z_2-z_1)$$
$$= ax_2+by_2 + cz_2 - (ax_1+by_1+cz_1) = d - d = 0$$

---

> I also have a few questions. is $e_1$ just another convention for $\hat i$? In the lecture he says that $e$ is a basis vector, but I've never really understood what a basis vector is.

A basis for a vector space is a collection of vectors $\{\hat e_1,\ldots, \hat e_N\}$ such that any vector $\vec v$ can be written uniquely as a sum $\vec v = \sum_{n=1}^N c_n \hat e_n$, where the $c_n$'s are just numbers.  If the vector space has an inner product, it is particularly useful to work with *orthonormal* bases such that
$$\hat e_i \cdot \hat e_j = \begin{cases}0 & i\neq j\\ 1 & i=j\end{cases}$$
in which case its very easy to find the coefficients, because $c_n = \hat e_n \cdot \vec v$.

For the vector space $\mathbb R^3$, one frequently uses the so-called standard basis
$$\hat e_1 = \langle 1,0,0\rangle \quad \hat e_2 = \langle 0,1,0\rangle \quad \hat e_3 = \langle 0,0,1\rangle$$
Some also call $\{\hat e_1,\hat e_2,\hat e_3\} \equiv \{\hat i,\hat j,\hat k\}$. There's no problem with that, but it makes shorthand (like $\vec v= \sum_{n=1}^N c_n \hat e_n$) impossible, and it's also rather a pain to extend to higher dimensional spaces, simply because you need to come up with more letters to use $\{\hat i,\hat j,\hat k, \hat \ell, \hat m ,\ldots \}$.

Answer (score 0):

If ax+ by+ cz= d then taking x= y= 0, z= d/c so (0, 0, d/c) is a point on that plane.  Similarly, taking x= z= 0, y= d/b. (0, d/b, 0) is another point on that plane.  That means that the vector <0, -d/b, d/c> is a vector lying in the plane.

The dot product of <0, -d/b, d/c> with <a, b, c> is 0(a)- (d/b)b+ (d/c)c= 0- d+ d= 0.  Those two vectors are at right angle to one another.

Taking y= z= 0, x= d/a so (d/a, 0, 0) is a third point on that plane.  The vector <d/a, 0, -d/c> is a second vector lying in the plane.  The dot product of <d/a, 0, -d/c> and <a, b, c> is a(d/a)+ 0(b)+ c(-d/c)= d- d= 0. Those two vectors are at right angles to one another.

Since <a, b, c> is perpendicular to two independent vectors in the plane, it is normal to the plane.

Answer (score 0):

You are given that the equation of the plane is

$a x + b y + c z = d \hspace{24pt} (1) $

The above equation can be written as

$ (a, b, c) \cdot ( x - x_0, y - y_0, z - z_0 ) = 0  \hspace{24pt} (2)$

where the "$\cdot$" denotes the inner or dot product between two vectors, and
provided that $a x_0 + b y_0 + c z_0 = d$, i.e. the point $(x_0, y_0,z_0 )$ lies in the plane.

What equation $(2)$ says is that the vector $(a,b,c)$ is perpendicular to any line segment connecting the two points $(x, y, z)$ and $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$.  Generalizing $(2)$, if $(x_1, y_1, z_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2, z_2)$ are any two points on the plane, then

$ (a, b, c) \cdot (x_2 - x_1, y_2 - y_1, z_2 - z_1 ) = 0 $

Thus the vector $(a,b,c) $ is perpendicular to any line segment that lies in the plane $a x + b y + c z = d $.

Finally, it is evident that the vector $(a, b, c)$ can be decomposed into $ a e_1 + b e_2 + c e_3 $.